# OpenGL Uniform Name pointer as string

Tags: c++, opengl, shader, glm-math, uniform

```
Set_Up_Shader(unsigned int sShader, string Uni_s, glm::vec3 V3){
    int isu = glGetUniformLocation(sShader, &Uni_s[0]);
    glUniform3fv(isu, 1, glm::value_ptr(V3));
}
```

My question is: Apparently glGetUniformLocation argument 2 should be const char*. Will OpenGL delay/require const object? Is it dangerous to sent OpenGL reference to string object that soon will be destroyed?

Answer (score 3):

> Is it dangerous to sent OpenGL reference to string object that soon will be destroyed?

No.

See [OpenGL 4.6 API Core Profile Specification - 2.1 Execution Model](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf#page=30&zoom=100,168,522):

> Data binding occurs on call. This means that data passed to a GL command
>   are interpreted when that command is received. Even if the command requires a
>   pointer to data, those data are interpreted when the call is made, and any subsequent
>   changes to the data have no effect on the GL

Answer (score 2):

No, your `char *` can be converted to a `const char *` without problems and the `const char *` argument is *immediately* used to look up the uniform location.

Regardless, it is slightly nicer to pass `Uni_s.c_str()`, as that is easier to grep.